# metamask Gas price must be greater than 0

Tags: metamask, gas-price

I am using a private block chain that has zero gas prices.  When I try to
set the gas price to zero in MetaMask, I get the error,
"Gas price must be greater than 0".   Is there anyway to use a zero gas
price in MetaMask?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to use a zero gas price in MetaMask?

Apparently no. At least not according to the current implementation, which considers 0 as an invalid value as you can see [here](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/3732c5f71ef60d6913f81e4d4623b9ddee11e3c0/ui/hooks/useGasFeeErrors.js#L69), which later triggers the error you are seeing [here](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/0c531f8b0101a4d39a20f8bda5582f707ac18d20/ui/helpers/constants/gas.js#L28).

You could easily change that behavior by modifying the metamask implementation to consider 0 as a valid input. It seems like you'd only need to modify [this](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/3732c5f71ef60d6913f81e4d4623b9ddee11e3c0/ui/hooks/gasFeeInput/useGasFeeErrors.js#L71) line and [that one](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/3732c5f71ef60d6913f81e4d4623b9ddee11e3c0/ui/hooks/useGasFeeErrors.js#L69). Changing the calls to [`bnLessThanEqualTo`](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/3732c5f71ef60d6913f81e4d4623b9ddee11e3c0/ui/helpers/utils/util.js#L399) by calls to [`bnLessThan`](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/3732c5f71ef60d6913f81e4d4623b9ddee11e3c0/ui/helpers/utils/util.js#L399).

I hope that answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hows it going, im still VERY new at this myself (day 4), but what I did personally to get going was, I used faucets to funnel my test wallet, several times.

https://www.rinkebyfaucet.com/

https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby

I couldn't configure my Metamask to 0 either so as a fix, I was told to give myself a bunch of Ethereum on my private node and I haven't yet learned how to do that. But to have the gas set to 0, I haven't been able to do.

I hope this helps and if not, I hope you find your answer.